# ToList with Capacity?

Tags: c#

When we do `.ToList()` for an `IEnumerable`, the list can potentially reallocate while scanning the `IEnumerable` because it doesn't know the size upfront. If the size is known, is there a simple way to avoid the performance penalty? Something to the effect of initializing a `List` with the required capacity and then copying the `IEnumerable` into it? Ideally something as simple as `.ToList(capacity)` (which doesn't exist).

Comment: `ToList` just calls the `List<T>(IEnumerable<T>)` constructor which checks if the source implements `ICollection<T>` and uses the count to set the capacity.

Comment: @Lee Unfortunately that stops working if the intermediate source "loses" length/count information, even when it should be available - for example, `listOf5Strings.OrderBy( s => s ).ToList()` (because the internal `OrderedEnumerable<T>` doesn't implement `ICollection<T>` or `IReadOnlyCollection<T>` even though it should. (It'd also be nice if Linq added support for "hints" when count information isn't accurately known, such as an upper-bound on the count, such as when using `Where` and `Take`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In cases when the capacity is part of `IEnumerable<T>` that is also an `ICollection<T>`, the library will allocate at the correct capacity.

Here is a [reference implementation of `List<T>(IEnumerable<T> source)`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs), which is invoked when you call `ToList()`:

```
public List(IEnumerable<T> collection) {
    if (collection==null)
        ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentNullException(ExceptionArgument.collection);
    Contract.EndContractBlock();

    ICollection<T> c = collection as ICollection<T>;
    if( c != null) {
        int count = c.Count;
        if (count == 0) {
            _items = _emptyArray;
        } else {
            _items = new T[count];
            c.CopyTo(_items, 0);
            _size = count;
        }
    } else {                
        _size = 0;
        _items = _emptyArray;
        // This enumerable could be empty.  Let Add allocate a new array, if needed.
        // Note it will also go to _defaultCapacity first, not 1, then 2, etc.

        using(IEnumerator<T> en = collection.GetEnumerator()) {
            while(en.MoveNext()) {
                Add(en.Current);                                    
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note how the constructor behaves when `collection` implements `ICollection<T>`: rather than iterating the content and calling `Add` for each item, it allocates the internal `_items` array, and copies the content into it without reallocations.

In situations when the capacity is *not* embedded in class implementing `IEnumerable<T>`, you can easily define one yourself, using a combination of standard methods:

```
public static class ToListExtension {

    public static List<T> ToList<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int capacity) 
    {
        var res = new List<T>(capacity);
        res.AddRange(source);
        return res;
    }

}
```